# React native fresh install ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "transform-runtime" specified

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, babeljs

#### update

This worked for me per @digit comment

```
"dependencies": {
        "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.45.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "2.0.0",
    ...
},
```

I followed [the instructions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) for building projects in native code for macos > ios. I ran `react-native run-ios` and I got the error in the title... Any thoughts? My thoughts are at the end if you want to read it.

```
Unknown plugin "transform-runtime" specified in "<myprojectdir>/node_modules/regenerator-transform/package.json" at 0, attempted to resolve relative to "<myprojectdir>/node_modules/regenerator-transform" (While processing preset: "<myprojectdir>/node_modules/babel-preset-react-native/index.js")
```

#### package.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.46.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "2.1.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
```

#### my npm & node versions

```
➜  nativeapp npm -v
4.6.1
➜  nativeapp node -v
v8.1.3
```

#### Thank you for looking. Below is my unrelated ranting about my react native but I do genuinely seek some guidance if you have any.

I watched the lectures of coders who works on react-native and I read as much as I can prior to my project and from what I can tell they are all geniuses. I am not being sarcastic I sincerely think that. Yet I fail to understand why my experience with react native is so bad. I mean ... fresh install ... should work? I do not know how many expo projects I have created and moved my stuff around before this because every freakin time I installed a package from npm, everything broke.

I've been a full time coder for 8 years and I've worked projects using things from bash to perl to python to php to golang to mysql to mongo to jquery to angular to vue to vanillajs to ionic to java to C to R yet I do not think I have ever been this frustrated with any new stack I have ever worked on.

What am I missing? What is it that I am doing wrong? Please somebody tell me because I am about to lose my mind and throw my laptop out the window. I spend my time debugging errors instead of making progress in my project. I get up in the morning two hours before work to work on this project and I work on it at home after work... It is 8PM and I've been trying to run the app for two hours now.

I am beginning to think I am the only one with these problems thus I am the cause. I see all these companies using react native and it does not make sense for any company to invest in something that is going to make its developers have the same experience as me. Just spending time on getting it to open.

Sorry about my ranting and please note that I care more about fixing the issue.

I am just passionate about what I do and I do not like spending my hours and not making progress for reasons that I do not expect to have. Thx for looking

Comment: This might work: delete the `package-lock.json` and run `npm install`. Think it's to do with NPM5 not correctly installing dev dependencies among other things.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14843

Comment: @digit I found [my solution in your github link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14843#issuecomment-313240326). Please feel free to post it as a reply so I can mark it as solution.

Comment: @AndrewLi Thank you for your comment bro

Comment: @ODelibalta Oh yeah, you have to also delete node_modules, I forgot to mention that in my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this link https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14843,
this is a bugs related to the babel-preset-react-native for react native v0.46. For temporary solution

1) Remove .babelrc by doing `rm -rf .babelrc` inside root folder

2) Revert babel-preset-react-native to the version 2.0.0